# Possibility of listing a set of values to search for

Tags: java, search, if-statement

My question is: is there any possibility of listing a set of values to search for in an if-statement? Or is there a better way of doing this? 
for example:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
String searchTerm=input.next();

if(input==1d,2d,3d,4d,5c,1a,3x,5c,6b){
    // Do stuff
}
```

EDIT: very sorry, I did not realise my question wasn't completed, and even kind of wrong... Gosh. Fixed now.

Comment: Are those really strings to search in, e.g. `"1d", "2d"`, etc.?

Comment: [Collection.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) or [Collection.containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) maybe? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!Arrays.asList(1d,2d,3d,4d,5c,1a,3x,5c,6b).contains(input)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @m0skit0, what? He got it right. The `!` wasn't the only reason.

Comment: Today's correct for fast response and understanding my void peice of code. I blame 7 hours of coding, probably 5-6 to go as well before midnight. Oh the joy

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a list:

- Add the values to search for to the list.
- Check by using `List.contains(Object o)` [(documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) if the input is one of the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a List from the values and then check for contains

```
if (list.contains(input))
```

Comment: Yup.. any Collection will do

Answer (score 1):

Convert them into a `List` using [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and use `contains`:

```
if (!Arrays.asList("1d", "2d", "3d", "4d", "5c", "1a", "3x", "5c", "6b").contains(input)) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new collection and see if the value is found in there:

```
if(!(Arrays.AsList("1d", "2d", "3d", "4d").Contains(input))){ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the set of values in a collection. For example:

```
Set<String> invalidInputs = new HashSet<String>();
validInputs.add("1d"); //and all the rest
```

Then check to see if the set contains the input:

```
if(!invalidInputs.contains(input) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do individual comparisons using an if statement (this is without using Java's more advanced stuff). If you're looking to compare multiple values, I'd suggest using a Switch statement.

```
switch (input){
    case '1d': case '2d': case '3d': case '4d': case '5c': case '1a': case '3x': case '6b':
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using arrays.

```
String[] test= {"1d","2d","3d","4d","5c","1a","3x","5c","6b"};
        for(int i=0;i<test`length;i++)
            if(!input.contentEquals(test[i]))
            {
                //Something
            }
```